# Starting simplex tableau with initial feasible solution

Tags: linear-programming

I have the following LP

> Solve the following problem by the simplex tableau method starting with the basic
> feasible solution corresponding to the vertex (x1, x2) = (4, 0).

$$
\text{maximize  }z = -x_1 + 2x_ 2 \\
\text{subject to: } \\
3x_1 + 4x_2 = 12 \\
2x_ 1-x_ 2 \leqslant 12
$$

It is clear to me how to initialize when an initial solution is not given, but how could I build my table once it is given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. Since we have the initial vertex, we should before adjust the problem:

$$
3x_1+4x_2=12\\
2x_1-x_2+x_3=12\\
$$

Once it is adjusted, we should use the vertex and check how the restrictions work with them:

$$
3\cdot(4)+4\cdot(0)=12\\
2\cdot(4)-1\cdot(0)+x_3=12
$$

Wich makes $x_3=4$. So now, we can adapt our initial solution to $(4,0,4)$ and now we have an initial basis composed by $(x_1,x_3)$ and finally, we can build the tableau as:

|  | $x_1$ | $x_2$ | $x_3$ |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| z | -1 | 2 | 0 |  |
| $x_1$ | 3 | 4 | 0 | 12 |
| $x_3$ | 2 | -1 | 1 | 12 |